# Type out Green Eggs and Ham in vim

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, vim

The book Green Eggs and Ham by Dr. Seuss is famous for only having 50 different words in the entire story of the book.

Your task is to create a sequence of keystrokes that will result in the entire text of Green Eggs and Ham when applied to an empty file in the [vim](http://www.vim.org/) text editor, starting in normal mode with all default settings. Your keystrokes must not load any other files as part of their operation - all text must be generated within the editor itself.

Your final buffer must look exactly like [this file](http://pastebin.com/MRRpGXYx), although it can remain in whichever mode it ends up being in (you don't have to have a final `<Esc>` to return it to normal mode).

Chorded keystrokes like `<C-o>` or using Shift to type a capital letter count as a single keystroke.

The sequence of the fewest keystrokes to achieve this goal wins.

Comment: If somebody wants to create the Emacs equivalent of this question, they can. I'm not familiar enough with Emacs to know if it would make for an interesting question at all.

Comment: Also, "with all default settings" means that you aren't allowed to load settings from a `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Based on your "canonical" insert-entire-file answer, I take it the mode you leave the editor in after the insertion doesn't matter. Maybe this should be explicitly specified to clarify (i.e. you don't have to <Esc> out from insert-mode).

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to `<Esc>` out from insert mode, but you do have to start in normal.

Comment: As I see it, this question is on the edge of being off-topic. It's not a codegolf, it's a vimgolf (there is a page for that, a good one. Anyone interested should take a look). I also find the text to be too long, making it very time consuming to golf.

Comment: You lied: it is 51 words. Now I have to start over. (kidding)

Comment: It's more than 51 if you count capitalizations as different words.

Comment: Also, there is a small typo in there. I'm not sure if its meant as a test to see who used your reference text or not, so I won't point it out.

Comment: fixing the typo brings the unique word count to 50

Comment: I didn't even notice the typo myself. Thanks for pointing it out, though - I found it and fixed it.

Comment: Is invoking external commands using Vim keystrokes allowed, if the "Your keystrokes must not load any other files" rule is still followed?

Comment: If those external commands are not available on a default Vim installation, then yes, it would violate the "loading any other files" rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 1864 keystrokes

Somebody could probably write some code that produces a more optimal solution, but this beats the reference case for now. This is a damn mess, and I am ashamed I did it by hand.

First, we enter insert mode.

```
i
```

Then all this

```
That ]! That ]!
IDNlike that ]!

Do Y like$?

|;].
IDNlike$.

WPY LTB or tB?

IZ LTB or tB.
IZ LTanywB.
IDNlike$.
|;].

WPY LTin a h@?
WPY LT=a m@?

|in a h@.
|=a m@.
|B or tB.
|.
IDNlike$.
|;].

WPY ETin a box?
WPY ET=a fox?

Not_a box. Not =a fox.
Not_a h@. Not =a m@.
IZ ETB or tB.
IZ ETanywB.
IZ eat$.
|;].

WPY? CPY? In a car?
Eat them! Eat them! B they are.

IZ,X,_a car.

You may LT. You will see.
You may LTin a tree!

IZ,X_a tree.
Not_a car! You let me be.

|in a box.
|=a fox.
|in a h@.
|=a m@.
|B or tB.
|.
IDNlike$.
|;].

AQ! AQ! AQ! AQ!
CPY;wPY;on aQ?

Not_aQ! Not_a tree!
Not_a car! Sam! Let me be!

IZ,X,_a box.
IX,Z;=a fox.
:=a m@.
:in a h@.
:B or tB.
:anywB.
IDNlike$.
|;].

Say! In +? B_+!
WPY;cPY,_+?

IZ,X,_+.

WPY;cPY,_the rain?


IZ,X,_the rain.
Not_+. Not on aQ.
Not_a car. Not_a tree.
|;Sam;Y see.
Not_a h@. Not_a box.
Not =a m@. Not =a fox.
:B or tB.
|!

You do not like$?
|;].

CPY;wPY;=a g^?

IZ,X;=a g^!

WPY;cPY;on a b^?

IX,Z;on a b^.
IWN,WN;=a g^.

:in the rain.
:on aQ.
Not_+! Not_a tree!
Not_a car! You let me be!
|in a box.
|=a fox.
:in a h@.
|=a m@.
|B or tB.
|!

IDNlike$!
|;].

You do not LT. So Y say.
Try them! Try them! & Y may.
Try them and Y may;I say.

Sam! If Y will let me be,
I will try them. You will see.

Say! I like$!
I do! I LT;]!
& I wPETin a b^.
& I wPET=a g^.

!ETin the rain.
&_+. & on aQ.
&_a car. &_a tree.
They are so good;so good;Y see!

So I will ETin a box.
!ET=a fox.
!ETin a h@.
!ET=a m@.
!ETB and tB.
Say! I will ETanywB!

I do so like$!

Thank Y! Thank Y;]!
```

Hit escape to enter command mode. And unravel the compressed stuff. Order matters, as I've compressed some compressed text.

```
<Esc>
%s/|/|anywB/g
%s/:/IWNET/g
%s/|/IDNLT/g
%s/Z/ wPnot/g
%s/X/ cPnot/g
%s/&/And/g
%s/+/the dark/g
%s/@/ouse/g
%s/^/oat/g
%s/Y/you/g
%s/IDN/I do not /g
%s/LT/like them /g
%s/]/Sam-I-am/g
%s/ET/eat them /g
%s/WN/ will not/g
%s/$/ green eggs and ham/g
%s/P/ould /g
%s/!/And I will /g
%s/Q/ train/g
%s/B/here/g
%s/_/ in /g
%s/=/with /g
%s/;/, /g
```

Comment: you got the wrong substitution for eat them, it's backwards. and you can cut the leading colons by using ed mode which stays in command mode after commands.

Comment: @hildred I actually started with the full text, did a global replace and added the full text to compressed text to another file. Must have forgotten to reverse that one :(

Comment: If you replace `so good;so good;` with `<Esc>2aso good;<Esc>a`, you can save three keystrokes. Also, replace `iThat ]! That]!<Enter>` at the beginning with `2iThat ]! <Esc>xo` for another three.

Comment: Also, since `DN` doesn't appear elsewhere, you can remove the `I` from `IDN` and `I do not ` in the replace statement with those two expressions in it.

Comment: And, replace all instances of `IDNlike$!<Enter>|;].` with `1` and input `%s/1/IDNlike$!\n|;]./g` to save about 20 keystrokes or so.

Answer (score 6):

## 3,470 keystrokes

```
i<entire text of file>
```

The text file is 3,469 characters long, so typing "i" to put it in insert mode and typing out each character individually will take 3,470 keystrokes.

Comment: Lol @ pure brute force

Comment: This is intended mostly as a last-place reference solution more than anything.

Comment: yet it's currently the best contestant as well :-) (no, I'm not going to participate; sorry)

Comment: You more of an Emacs person? :-)